# Add title attibute to categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In single.php I use `<?php the_category(', '); ?>`. This function lists categories attached to post, but title attribute (on hover) is missing. How can I add this? I've tried with adding a filter in functions.php and making a new function like `<?php the_better_category('%cat% - my text'); ?>`, but the result is miserable.

Comment: What do you want the title text to be? The category name? Description?

Comment: Category name and my own text.

Answer (score 0):

From the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title):

```
<?php single_cat_title( '', true ); ?>
```

The first part (in single quotes) will output whatever custom text you put there before the category title and true means it will display (false is use in PHP).

Have you tried:

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
    }
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
?>
```